# Concurrent Merge sort

Tags: java, mergesort

I have been assigned in a class to make a concurrent merge sort using `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>` for the queue. The problem is I can't make it to work correctly, the output I get is not ordered, i suppose it is because the recursive call should wait before the final merge call, but i don't know how to do it, or even if that's the problem.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class Main {
    private static final int M = 4; // Number of worker threads
    private static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> taskQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        }
        mergeSort(input, 0, input.length - 1);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
    }

    private static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int l, int r) {
        if (l < r) {
            int m = (l + r) / 2;

            // Enqueue sort tasks for left and right subarrays
            taskQueue.offer(() -> mergeSort(arr, l, m));
            taskQueue.offer(() -> mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r));

            // Start worker threads
            startWorkerThreads();

            // Enqueue merge task for subarrays
            taskQueue.offer(() -> merge(arr, l, m, r));

            // Start worker threads again for merging
            startWorkerThreads();
        }
    }

    private static void startWorkerThreads() {
        Thread[] workers = new Thread[M];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            workers[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                Runnable task;
                while ((task = taskQueue.poll()) != null) {
                    task.run();
                }
            });
            workers[i].start();
        }




    }



    private static void merge(int[] arr, int l, int m, int r) {
        int n1 = m - l + 1;
        int n2 = r - m;

        int[] left = new int[n1];
        int[] right = new int[n2];

        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            left[i] = arr[l + i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            right[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
        }

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = l;
        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
                arr[k] = left[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                arr[k] = right[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while (i < n1) {
            arr[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while (j < n2) {
            arr[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `Thread.sleep`, and works for small arrays, but for bigger ones it's bad.

Comment: In order to wait for threads, you need to call "join" method: `for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {workers[i].join();}`

Comment: This would be simpler with a bottom up merge sort. Split the array into M parts, and use M threads to create M sorted runs. Then use M/2 threads to merge the M runs into M/2 runs, until the result is a single run.

Comment: For M = 4, split array into 4 parts, and create 4 threads to sort the 4 parts, thread 0, 1, 2, 3.  Thread 1 and 3 exit after sorting their part.  Thread 2 waits for thread 3 (join) and merges part 2 and 3 and exits. Thread 0 waits for thread 1 (join) and merges part 0 and 1, then waits for thread 2 (join), and merges the two halves and exits. The main thread can be thread 0 to avoid creating an unneeded thread.